# How to assign a coordinate reference system to x (buffer) datasets of x iterations in a for loop - R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, buffer, for-loop

My aims are 1) to create different buffer sizes around three points via a for loop, 2) to assign a coordinate system to each buffer for each iteration, and 3) to store each buffer in a list `buffer_vars` that was initialized before the loop. Aims 1 and 3 are working, however when I try to verify the coordinate system of the first item in the list `buffer_vars`, the console gives `Coordinate Reference System: NA`, even though I assigned a coordinate system to each buffer at each iteration via `st_crs(buf_i, crs=crs)`.

What needs to be changed in the code in order to assign a coordinate system to each buffer in the list `buffer_vars`?

Code:

```
#necessary libraries
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)
library(utils)
library(rgeos)
library(gstat)

## == create point features dataset == ##

#initialize coordinates
points_long <- c(6.564702, 6.534903, 6.534677)
points_lat <- c(51.54378, 51.59492, 51.59278)

#merge columns to one dataset
points_df <- data.frame(points_long, points_lat)

# convert to spatial dataframe
points_sf <- st_as_sf(points_df, coords = c("points_long", "points_lat"), crs=4326)

## == Project data into a planar coordinate system (here UTM zone 32) so that buffer calculations can be done == ##

utmStr <- "+proj=utm +zone=%d +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80"
crs <- CRS(sprintf(utmStr, 32))
points_sf <- as_Spatial(points_sf)
points_sf_utm <- spTransform(points_sf, crs)
#convert back to sf so that variable can be used as argument in st_buffer
points_sf_utm <- st_as_sf(points_sf_utm)

## == Create for loop that generates x number of buffers around the three defined points.

#initialize buffer parameters
bufs = list(25, 50, 100, 400, 800) #in meters
#create empty list to store buffer results into
buffer_vars = list()

# for loop
for(i in bufs){
  buf_i <- st_buffer(points_sf_utm, i) #create buffer around 3 points
  assign(paste("buffer", i, "m", sep = ""), buf_i) #assign buffer to variable name that relates to buffer x
  
  #assign coordinate system to buffer
  buf_i <- st_as_sf(buf_i)
  st_crs(buf_i, crs=crs)  #planar coordinate system (UTM zone 32)

  #store variable in loop to the list that was initialized before the loop
  buffer_vars[[paste("buffer", i, "m", sep = "")]] <- buf_i #store as item in list
  
  #export option
  layer <- paste("buffer", i, "m", sep = "")
  print(layer) #verify
  sf::st_write(buf_i, dsn='C:/Test',layer=layer, driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
  
}

summary(buffer_vars) #examine each item (i.e. buffer) in list 

st_crs(buffer_vars[1]) #Coordinate Reference System: NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Indexing with one square bracket returns a subset list of a list:

```
> L = list(1,2,3)
> L[2]
[[1]]
[1] 2
```

Indexing with double square brackets returns the list element:

```
> L[[2]]
[1] 2
```

So this is actually returning a list with one element:

```
> st_crs(buffer_vars[1]) #
Coordinate Reference System: NA
```

And `st_crs` seems programmed to say that anything that is a list and nothing more complex has an NA CRS:

```
> st_crs(list("Hello"))
Coordinate Reference System: NA
```

If you use the double square brackets to get an element, you are returning a spatial object, and it works:

```
> st_crs(buffer_vars[[1]]) #
    Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs 
  wkt:
PROJCRS["unknown",
    BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",
        DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
 [etc]
```